# Backbone - cannot traverse through object properties

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections, model, fetch

I'm trying to traverse through the properties of a json file. You can see my code in http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/qRV7k/. In line 38, it should return the values of "name" and "age" in the console. Anyone know what im doing wrong?

```
    var app = {};

     app.model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        age: '',
        name: ''
       }
      });

    app.collec = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.model2,
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/name/betty/age/22',
    parse: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.info("init ...");
        this.fetch({
            success: function (obj, s, jqxhr) {
                // console.log(s);
            },
            error: function (funds) {
                console.error("Error in fetch in collec");
            }
        });
    }
});

app.model_with_collec = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //console.info(this);
        this.set({
            my_kids: new app.collec()
        });

        var mo = this.get('my_kids').models;
       console.log(mo);
        console.log(mo.attributes);//undefined is returned

    }

});

new app.model_with_collec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code like this it will be executed sequentially and will reach the console.log before the server even respond to the rest call. So it's normal that it prints undefined.

Here the code that will print what you want :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
    <!-- /inladen bower_components -->
    <script>
        var app = {};

        app.model2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                age: '',
                name: ''
            }
        });

        app.collec = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: app.model2,
            url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/name/betty/age/22',
            parse: function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            initialize: function() {
                console.info("init ...");
                this.fetch({
                    success: function(obj, s, jqxhr) {
                        // console.log(s);
                    },
                    error: function(funds) {
                        console.error("Error in fetch in collec");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        app.model_with_collec = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                //console.info(this);
                this.set({
                    my_kids: new app.collec()
                });

                this.get('my_kids').bind('reset', this.logAttributes, this);
            },

            logAttributes: function() {

                var mo = this.get('my_kids').models;

                console.log(mo);
                console.log(mo[0].attributes);
            }

        });

        new app.model_with_collec();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, tried it http://jsfiddle.net/gerlstar/3mASU/ but it is not displaying the console..

Comment: Hmm. Am I missing something because it's still not working. The console in the jsfiddle doesnt show anything. Same goes if I try it on my Firefox. http://imgur.com/vbLLZVu. It shows an empty array instead of an array with length = 1

Comment: when I click run on top of this example http://jsfiddle.net/3mASU/1/, I have this output :init ...
GET http://echo.jsontest.com/name/betty/age/22
[Object {cid="c2", attributes=Object, collection=Object, ...}], with the attributes populated with the data from the rest service

Comment: I see it but when I hit "Run" on jsfiddle, that {object ... } changes to [].. What did you type to display the {Object ... } again?

Comment: I think that there is an issue with jsfiddle because when I add 'alert(1);' in the first line of the 'logAttributes' function, it always print the right result, anyway I have edited my answer to include the full html code that works.